# Visual studio stopped performing custom build steps

Tags: visual-studio, protocol-buffers, custom-build-step

Not sure how to address this problem, maybe someone has faced this before and can give a hint where to look.

The problem is that my visual studio project has proto file with a custom build tep assigned to it:

`..\*some path to a protoc.exe*\protoc --proto_path=%(RootDir)%(Directory) --cpp_out=%(RootDir)%(Directory) %(FullPath)`

Everything worked fine, until some day it stopped and I have no idea why. Maybe I have screwed up some environmental variable or some setting or something else. The problem also extends itself to other projects that had some custom build steps generated when I used CmakeGui to generate a visual studio project. Such steps have a description set "Compiling %(Filename).proto..." which does not appear in the output. Almost as if it was completely ignored, yet compiler can't build the project because there are references to generated files inside the project.

Any advice on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue resolved itself after I did a repair using visual installer.
Wtf was the problem is still a mistery though.